# "Box: laravel/homestead-7" producing "sh.exe":box:: command not found"

Tags: php, laravel, git-bash

Goal: install homestead so that I can install laravel

I am following the [official instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead) trying to install homestead.

I have so far on the Git Bash terminal:

1. Installed the vagrant box and Virtual box which works fine. Also added the laravel/homestead box to the vagrant installation
2. Cloned the Homestead Repo
3. Cloned the php7 brand of the Homestead Repo
4. Successfully ran 'bash init.sh'
5. Initialized Homestead by running "git clone -b php-7 https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead7

Now when I am trying to run:

```
box: laravel/homestead-7
```

The terminal gives me:

```
sh.exe": box:: command not found
```

Currently, the Homestead folder is sitting on the following path:

C:\Users\Gil.vagrant.d\boxes\homestead\Homestead

Does anyone know why this is happening and the solution?

What I have researched so far on Google but does not seem to address my particular problem:

[cant-add-laravel-homestead-box-ssl-certificate-prob-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527525/cant-add-laravel-homestead-box-ssl-certificate-prob-windows)

[cant-install-vagrant-box-laravel-homestead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095225/cant-install-vagrant-box-laravel-homestead)

[cant-add-laravel-homestead-box-ssl-certificate-prob-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527525/cant-add-laravel-homestead-box-ssl-certificate-prob-windows)

[the-box-laravel-homestead-could-not-be-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750232/the-box-laravel-homestead-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read more carefully:

> ### Next, add then the `box` directive to the top of your `~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml` file (on a new line after --- mark):
>
> ### `...`

This means that you need to open the file named in a text editor and modify it.

Comment: thanks @Ignacio I wasnt sure what that meant. What is a box directive? I tried guessing that it might be the box directory so I added the absolute reference to the box directory after the --- mark on the yaml file but still doesn't work.

Comment: Just... put that text **as it is** into the file.

Comment: argh, I thought that I need to run that line on the terminal rather than actually adding it on. thanks