# error when try to add box laravel/homestead

Tags: laravel, homestead

Today, I try to add box laravel homestead following document in laravel home page. But I have an error in my laptop using windows 8.1. The first step, I installed vagrant, virtualbox and using syntax `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`. It's will show error log in git bash :

```
The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead"]
Error:
```

Then I try syntax: `vagrant box add laravel/homestead https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead`. It's will show error:

```
$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0) for provider:
    box: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead
    box:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.
```

Again, I run : `rm ~/.vagrant.d/tmp/*` and `vagrant up`. But not working.In addition, another computer everything good.What can I do, anyone?

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750232/the-box-laravel-homestead-could-not-be-found ?

Comment: Please also check here https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6754

Comment: yep, I checked.I has run: `vagrant init box/name` and `vagrant up` but show the same error

Comment: Can you try to run curl to see if it is working?

Comment: It isn't working, I try to add another `box/name` in `atlas.hashicorp.com` but not working

Comment: Since you're using gitbash did you try running this? cp /mingw64/bin/curl.exe /c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/bin/curl.exe

Comment: yep, I run it.It's working after I restart computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having a similar issue try checking the curl or you can simple copy one if you are using git bash under Windows.

```
cp /mingw64/bin/curl.exe /c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/bin/curl.exe
```

Comment: don't forget restart your computer :D